# Reading MS word file in C# with comments

Tags: c#, ms-word, comments

Currently i have a word document with comments added. The structure of the document is specified in the comment. The document contains embedded images.

Now i need to structurally read the document based on the comments and create a html file.
The problem is i cant capture the embedded image information currently.

```
        Comments comments = doc.Comments;
        foreach (Comment comment in comments)
        {
            String text = comment.Range.Text;
            String actualText = comment.Scope.Text;

        }
```

Can someone please help in capturing the embedded images.
Also i need the exact "html" format of the document. Currently the text appears plain without any paragraph information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Integrating Microsoft Word in your .NET applications [ CodeProject ]
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/WordInDotnet.aspx

This can help you. Just now you check the API methods. I believe that there are already methods in the API to list all files, and I think qeu you can programmatically, choose the method of viewing in HTML and then save it. Hope that helps. Have fun.

Comment: Thanks for the input.
I am able to use CopyImage and ClipBoard functionality to get the image details.
comment.Scope.CopyImage();
String completeData = Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.html).ToString();
This html content contains the path of "local image file" on the disk in temporary location.

Also comment.Scope.get_XML(false) get us the complete content in "xml" with image data as "bindata".

Comment: Notice that the link to **CodeProject** is not valid anymore, for the article was delete.